# How do I share a struct containing a phantom pointer among threads?

Tags: generics, rust, thread-safety, phantom-types

I have a structure that needs to be generic over a type, yet the type is not actually contained in the structure: it's used in methods of this structure, not in the structure itself. And so, the structure includes a `PhantomData` member:

```
pub struct Map<T> {
    filename: String,
    phantom: PhantomData<*const T>,
}
```

The phantom member is defined as a pointer because the structure does not actually own data of type `T`.  This is per advice in [the documentation of `std::marker::PhantomData`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/marker/struct.PhantomData.html):

> Adding a field of type `PhantomData<T>` indicates that your type owns data of type `T`. This in turn implies that when your type is dropped, it may drop one or more instances of the type `T`. This has bearing on the Rust compiler's drop check analysis.
>
> If your struct does not in fact own the data of type `T`, it is better to use a reference type, like `PhantomData<&'a T>` (ideally) or `PhantomData<*const T>` (if no lifetime applies), so as not to indicate ownership.

So the pointer seems to be the right choice here. This, however, causes the structure to no longer be `Send` nor `Sync`, because `PhantomData` is only `Send` and `Sync` if its type parameter is, and since pointers are neither, the whole thing isn't either. And so, code like this

```
// Given a master_map of type Arc<Map<Region>> ...
let map = Arc::clone(&master_map);

thread::spawn(move || {
    map.do_stuff();
});
```

fails to compile even though no `Region` values or even pointers are being moved:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `*const Region: std::marker::Send` is not satisfied in `Map<Region>`
  --> src/main.rs:57:9
   |
57 |         thread::spawn(move || {
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ `*const Region` cannot be sent between threads safely
   |
   = help: within `Map<Region>`, the trait `std::marker::Send` is not implemented for `*const Region`
   = note: required because it appears within the type `std::marker::PhantomData<*const Region>`
   = note: required because it appears within the type `Map<Region>`
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `std::marker::Send` for `std::sync::Arc<Map<Region>>`
   = note: required because it appears within the type `[closure@src/main.rs:57:23: 60:10 map:std::sync::Arc<Map<Region>>]`
   = note: required by `std::thread::spawn`

error[E0277]: the trait bound `*const Region: std::marker::Sync` is not satisfied in `Map<Region>`
  --> src/main.rs:57:9
   |
57 |         thread::spawn(move || {
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ `*const Region` cannot be shared between threads safely
   |
   = help: within `Map<Region>`, the trait `std::marker::Sync` is not implemented for `*const Region`
   = note: required because it appears within the type `std::marker::PhantomData<*const Region>`
   = note: required because it appears within the type `Map<Region>`
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `std::marker::Send` for `std::sync::Arc<Map<Region>>`
   = note: required because it appears within the type `[closure@src/main.rs:57:23: 60:10 map:std::sync::Arc<Map<Region>>]`
   = note: required by `std::thread::spawn`
```

Here's a [complete test case in the playground that exhibits this issue](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=e071c3e62268e943cd9f233a8ea098d6&version=stable&mode=debug):

```
use std::fmt::Debug;
use std::marker::PhantomData;
use std::sync::Arc;
use std::thread;

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Region {
    width: usize,
    height: usize,
    // ... more stuff that would be read from a file
}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Map<T> {
    filename: String,
    phantom: PhantomData<*const T>,
}

// General Map methods
impl<T> Map<T>
where
    T: Debug,
{
    pub fn new<S>(filename: S) -> Self
    where
        S: Into<String>,
    {
        Map {
            filename: filename.into(),
            phantom: PhantomData,
        }
    }

    pub fn do_stuff(&self) {
        println!("doing stuff {:?}", self);
    }
}

// Methods specific to Map<Region>
impl Map<Region> {
    pub fn get_region(&self) -> Region {
        Region {
            width: 10,
            height: 20,
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let master_map = Arc::new(Map::<Region>::new("mapfile"));
    master_map.do_stuff();
    let region = master_map.get_region();
    println!("{:?}", region);

    let join_handle = {
        let map = Arc::clone(&master_map);
        thread::spawn(move || {
            println!("In subthread...");
            map.do_stuff();
        })
    };

    join_handle.join().unwrap();
}
```

What is the best way to deal with this? This is what I've tried:

**Defining the phantom field as `PhantomData<T>`.** A proper value instead of a pointer. This works, but I'm wary of it because I've no idea what effect it has, if any, on Rust compiler's "drop check analysis", as per the docs quoted above.

**Defining the phantom field as `PhantomData<&'a T>`.** A reference. This should work, but it forces the structure to take an unneeded lifetime parameter, which propagates through my code. I'd rather not do this.

**Forcing the structure to implement `Send` and `Sync`.** This is what I'm actually doing at the moment:

```
unsafe impl<T> Sync for Map<T> {}
unsafe impl<T> Send for Map<T> {}
```

It seems to work, but those `unsafe impl`s are ugly and make me nervous.

To clarify what `T` is used for: It doesn't matter, really. It may not even be used, just provided as a marker for the type system. E.g. only needed so that `Map<T>` has a type parameter so different `impl` blocks can be provided:

```
impl<T> struct Map<T> {
    // common methods of all Maps
}

impl struct Map<Region> {
    // additional methods available when T is Region
}

impl struct Map<Whatever> {
    // additional methods available when T is Whatever, etc.
}
```

Comment: `PhantomData<&'static T>`, maybe? Or... no, that would require `T: 'static`.

Comment: Thanks! But yeah `'static` doesn't quite work for this, that'd be a pretty hefty constraint on the type. Also, to the bloke who asked what `T` is used for, and why not a reference: I'm sorry, I think I deleted you comment trying to delete a response of mine that I mistyped >.< Will comment again below.

Comment: So I didn't think the use of `T` was relevant to the question because it isn't used in the structure, so it makes no difference on whether it's `Sync` or `Send`. If you look in the playground example I linked, you'll see I use it to define a `impl` with methods that are only available when `T` is a specific type. So that's a possible use. Should I edit my question? As for using a reference: that's less than ideal because then the structure has to be defined as `struct Map<'a, T>`, so everywhere it's used you have to specify a lifetime. A meaningless lifetime, since it's not actually used.

Comment: That is brilliant, indeed that's what I need, many thanks.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There's another option: `PhantomData<fn() -> T>`. `fn() -> T` has the same [variance](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/phantom-data.html#table-of-phantomdata-patterns) as `T` and `*const T`, but unlike `*const T`, it implements both `Send` and `Sync`. It also makes it clear that your struct only ever *produces* instances of `T`. (If some methods take `T` as input, then `PhantomData<fn(T) -> T>` might be more appropriate).

```
#[derive(Debug)]
struct Map<T> {
    filename: String,
    phantom: PhantomData<fn() -> T>,
}
```

Answer (score 2):

#### Zero-sized marker traits

My preferred solution is to use use throwaway structs for this purpose:

```
#[derive(Debug)]
struct Map<T: ThingMarker> {
    filename: String,
    marker: T,
}

trait ThingMarker: Default {}

#[derive(Debug, Default)]
struct RegionMarker;
impl ThingMarker for RegionMarker {}

// General Map methods
impl<T: ThingMarker> Map<T>
where
    T: Debug,
{
    pub fn new<S>(filename: S) -> Self
    where
        S: Into<String>,
    {
        Map {
            filename: filename.into(),
            marker: Default::default(),
        }
    }
   // ...
}

impl Map<RegionMarker> {
    pub fn get_region(&self) -> Region { /* ... */ }
}

fn main() {
    let master_map = Arc::new(Map::<RegionMarker>::new("mapfile"));
    // ...
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=3c74792325bfbf67aa13f4b70b309649&version=stable&mode=debug)

> a structure that needs to be generic over a type, yet the type is not actually contained in the structure: it's used in methods of this structure, not in the structure itself.

My rationale is that you don't actually need to parameterize your struct over the type *used in the methods*, you just need to parameterize it over *some* type. This is a prime case for just having your own trait. It's probably even more powerful as you can have associated types or constants on the trait implementation.

#### Narrow implementation

> but those `unsafe impl`s are ugly and make me nervous.

As they should. One simple modification is to create your own wrapper type that narrowly implements those traits:

```
// Pick a better name for this struct
#[derive(Debug)]
struct X<T>(PhantomData<*const T>);

impl<T> X<T> {
    fn new() -> Self {
        X(PhantomData)
    }
}

unsafe impl<T> Sync for X<T> {}
unsafe impl<T> Send for X<T> {}
```

This prevents "accidentally" implementing these traits for your type if some other field is not `Send` or `Sync`.

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=0f8fa63258529d3850606d07ab90e1c5&version=stable&mode=debug)