# Making a struct outlive a parameter given to a method of that struct

Tags: rust, lifetime, ffi

I am looking for a way to ensure a struct outlives the parameter given to a method of that struct.
Even if the struct doesn't hold a reference to that data after leaving the method.

This is for wrapped raw pointers fed to an FFI. I want to guarantee that the struct implementing the FFI outlives the `Option<&'a Any>` I use to feed the Rust object to the pointer wrapper.

`Context` is the FFI wrapper.
`Data` holds different types that map to FFI types. The FFI functions copies all these types immediately before returning.

Except raw pointers.

So I add a lifetime specifier to `Context` just for those and use that in `send_data()`.

But somehow this is not enough. I expected below code to not compile.

Edit: someone one the Rust Discord suggested making `&self` `mut`able in `send_data()`. This has the desired effect but my FFI is thread safe (and stateless) and `send_data()` is time critical. So I would very much like to avoid this.

```rust
use std::any::Any;
use std::marker::PhantomData;

struct IntegerArray<'a> {
    data: &'a [i32],
}

struct WrappedRawPointer<'a> {
    ptr: *const std::ffi::c_void,
    _marker: PhantomData<&'a ()>,
}

impl<'a> WrappedRawPointer<'a> {
    fn new(data: Option<&'a dyn Any>) -> Self {
        Self {
            ptr: data
                .map(|p| p as *const _ as *const std::ffi::c_void)
                .unwrap_or(std::ptr::null()),
            _marker: PhantomData,
        }
    }
}

enum Data<'a, 'b> {
    IntegerArray(IntegerArray<'a>),
    WrappedRawPointer(WrappedRawPointer<'b>),
}

struct Context<'a> {
    ctx: u32,
    _marker: PhantomData<&'a ()>,
}

impl<'a> Context<'a> {
    fn new() -> Self {
        Self {
            ctx: 0, // Call FFI to initialize context
            _marker: PhantomData,
        }
    }

    fn send_data(&self, data: Data<'_, 'a>) {
        match data {
            Data::IntegerArray(_i) => (),      // Call FFI function
            Data::WrappedRawPointer(_p) => (), // Call FFI function
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let ctx = Context::new();

    {
        let some_float: f32 = 42.0;
        ctx.send_data(
            Data::WrappedRawPointer(
                WrappedRawPointer::new(
                    Some(&some_float)
                )
            )
        );

        // I would like rustc to complain 
        // here that some_float does not
        // outlive ctx
    }

    // Explicitly drop outside
    // the previous block to 
    // prevent rustc from being
    // clever
    drop(ctx);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Making `send_data` take `&mut self` instead of `&self` works because it makes the type of the `self` parameter *invariant* with respect to the type `Self`. [Subtyping and Variance](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/subtyping.html) is described in the Rustonomicon, as well as other questions here on Stack Overflow (see below).

Since you want invariance even when `self` is an immutable reference, that suggests that the variance of `Context<'a>` *itself* is wrong: it is covariant in `'a`, but it should be invariant. You can fix this by changing the type argument to `PhantomData` to something that is also invariant in `'a`:

```
struct Context<'a> {
    ctx: u32,
    _marker: PhantomData<*mut &'a ()>,  // or Cell<&'a ()>, or fn(&'a ()) -> &'a (), etc.
}
```

`PhantomData` is not just something you add mechanically to make the compiler not yell at you. The specific form of the type argument to `PhantomData` tells the compiler *how* your struct is related to its type and lifetime parameters (when the compiler can't figure it out by itself). In this case you want to tell the compiler that a `Context<'some_long_lifetime>` *can't* be substituted for a `Context<'a_much_shorter_lifetime>` even though its fields would all allow that substitution.

### Some more questions on variance

- [How can this instance seemingly outlive its own parameter lifetime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42637911/how-can-this-instance-seemingly-outlive-its-own-parameter-lifetime)
- [Why does linking lifetimes matter only with mutable references?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32165917/why-does-linking-lifetimes-matter-only-with-mutable-references)
- [How do I share a struct containing a phantom pointer among threads?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50200197/how-do-i-share-a-struct-containing-a-phantom-pointer-among-threads) (may be relevant if `Context` should be `Send` or `Sync`)

Comment: Awesome, cheers!
I just re-read the section of the Rustonomicon on Subtyping & Variance but that answer would still not have occurred to me.
On that note: I didn't added PhantomData to make the compiler yell at me, not the opposite. :)

Comment: When using this in my crate I now get an unexpected error when I do not call `drop()` explicitly (see here: https://github.com/virtualritz/nsi/blob/1e5ebf1258f68434598083f0dcb3c135ef8228f0/src/tests.rs#L64):
`140: foo dropped here while still borrowed. Borrow might be used here, when c is dropped and runs the Drop code for type Context`
While on the playground the modified example compiles w/o `drop()` (https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=10f186b493948d7a5444a95150691666)
I do not understand what am I doing different here.